# jQuery Find / Replace in Lots of Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, find

I am using jQuery and I need to create a Find / Replace form for text that is pulled from a text file "example.txt".

First, here is the HTML:

```
<div id="outbox" class="outbox">
<h3>Output</h3>
<div id="output"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
<h3>Text File Location</h3>
<br />
<form id="prac" action="prac9.html">
    <input id="locator" type="text" value="example.txt" /> <br />
    <input id="btnlocate" value="Load" type="button" />
</form>
<br />
<h3>String Search</h3>
<form id="prac2" action="prac9.html">
    <div id='input'><input type='text' id='fancy-input'/> ...Start Typing</div> <br />

</form>
<br />
<h3>Find / Replace String</h3>
<form id="prac3" action="prac9.html">
    <input id="findtxt" type="text" value="" /> Find <br />
    <input id="replacetxt" type="text" value="" /> Replace<br />
    <input id="btnreplace" value="Find & Replace" type="button" />
</form>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery/JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#btnlocate').click(function () {

    $.get($('#locator').val(), function (data) {
        var lines = data.split("\n");
        $.each(lines, function (n, elem) {
            $('#output').append('<div>' + elem + '</div>');
            // text loaded and printed
        });
    });
});

/* SEARCH FUNCTION */

$(function () {       

    $('#fancy-input').keyup(function () {
        var regex;
        $('#output').highlightRegex();
        try { regex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'ig') }
        catch (e) { $('#fancy-input').addClass('error') }

        if (typeof regex !== 'undefined') {
            $(this).removeClass('error');
            if ($(this).val() != '')
                $('#output').highlightRegex(regex);
        }
    })
});

 /* SEARCH FUNCTION FOR FIND REPLACE */
 $(function () {
    $('#findtxt').keyup(function () {
        var regex;
        $('#output').highlightRegex();
        try { regex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'ig') }
        catch (e) { $('#findtxt').addClass('error') }

        if (typeof regex !== 'undefined') {
            $(this).removeClass('error');
            if ($(this).val() != '')
                $('#output').highlightRegex(regex);
        }
        })
    });

 /* regexp escaping function */

  RegExp.escape = function (str) {
      return String(str).replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');
  };

    $('#btnreplace').click(function () {
        var needle = $('#findtxt').val();
        var newneedle = $('#replacetxt').val();
        var haystack = $('#output').text();
      //  var regex = new RegExp(needle, "g");
        haystack = haystack.replace(new RegExp(RegExp.escape(needle), "g"), newneedle);
        console.log(haystack);
    });
```

As you may have noticed, I have used a plugin "jQuery Highlight Regex Plugin v0.1.1" if that's relevant.

http://pastebin.com/HmqWmKsy is "example.txt" if that's relevant also.

All I need is a simple way of doing this find / replace but all the stuff on the web has yet to help me.

If you need anymore info, let me know please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track using `replace` and a regular expression. You want to add the "global" flag (`g`), and you'll have to create the expression via `new RegExp(string)` because your `needle` is a string. E.g.:

```
haystack = haystack.replace(new RegExp(needle, "g"), newNeedle); // BUT SEE BELOW
```

The above *almost* works, except that if there are any characters in `needle` that are special in regular expressions (`*`, `[]`, and the like), obviously `new RegExp` will try to interpret them. Unfortunately, `RegExp` doesn't have a standard means of escaping all of the regex characters in a string, but you can add it:

```
RegExp.escape = function(str) {
  return String(str).replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');
};
```

(That's from [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), but we can just copy it rather than actually using the entire library, it's MIT-licensed. Be sure to attribute in your source. Or alternately use [this version](http://simonwillison.net/2006/Jan/20/escape/#p-6) from elsewhere.)

So we end up with:

```
haystack = haystack.replace(new RegExp(RegExp.escape(needle), "g"), newNeedle);
```

---

Here's a full working example: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ugetas) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ugetas/edit)

HTML:

```
<div>
  <label>Haystack:
    <br><textarea id="theHaystack" rows="5" cols="50">Haystack with test*value more than once test*value</textarea>
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Needle:
    <br><input type="text" id="theNeedle" value="test*value">
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>New Needle:
    <br><input type="text" id="theNewNeedle" value="NEW TEXT">
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>New haystack:
    <br><textarea readonly id="theNewHaystack" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="theButton">Replace</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
RegExp.escape = function(str) {
  return String(str).replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');
};
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#theButton").click(function() {
    var haystack = $("#theHaystack").val(),
        needle   = $("#theNeedle").val(),
        newNeedle = $("#theNewNeedle").val(),
        newHaystack;

    if (!haystack || !needle) {
      display("Please fill in both haystack and needle");
      return;
    }

    newHaystack = haystack.replace(
      new RegExp(RegExp.escape(needle), "g"),
      newNeedle);
    $("#theNewHaystack").val(newHaystack);
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

The haystack that is outputted has no changes, what am I missing?

Comment: @Henryccc: `replace` doesn't change the string in situ, it *returns* the changed string; see above where I'm assigning the result back to `haystack`: `haystack = haystack.replace(...);` not just `haystack.replace(...);`. Did you miss that part out?

Comment: Sorry, reupdated again, but even if I set it to `newhaystack = haystack.replace(...)` it still doesn't have an updated haystack. I don't totally understand haha.

Comment: @Henryccc: I'm not immediately seeing a problem with the new code you added. I've added a [full working example](http://jsbin.com/ugetas) to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I realised it was a different part of the code that was causing an issue! 
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Henryccc: Good deal! Glad that helped.